# Question over the writing of a function

Tags: calculus, definition, piecewise-continuity

This is a really silly question, I know, but I just wanted to know if I'm too "strict" or if it's really an error.

An exercise our professor given us start with this: be $f$ a function defined as
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{x}{x-1} \sqrt{x^2-1} & x \leq -1\quad \text{or}\quad x \geq 1 \\\\
x^2 - 1 & -1 < x < +1 
\end{cases}$$

- Question: is it legit to defined the function in the upper piece in the given range? I mean $x = 1$ is included, but I see $x-1$ in the denominator, and hence that range should have strict inequalities, that is: $x \leq -1$ or $x > 1$.

Am I right, or can this be defined in that way with no sin of error?

Thank you!

Comment: Ok! So you confirm it would be an error. Thank you! It's silly I know, but details lie in the meanders :D

Comment: As with any function given by a formula, the usual convention is that the domain is taken to be "all numbers for which the formula makes sense". The formulas you give make no sense for $x=1$, so even though the piecewise description "includes" the $x=1$ case, this function would not be defined at $x=1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, you're right. I meant $x \leq -1$ or $x \geq 1$. That is the original writing, in the paper. So I'm asking again, just to be sure, if the writing $x \geq 1$ is wrong or it can be fine, for $x = 1$ makes the function non existent...

Comment: I've always considered it bad taste to allow an $x$ in the piecewise domain that does not lead to a $y$-coordinate.  This doesn't make it wrong, but that's the problem with defining functions this way without specifying the domain and codomain *first*.

Comment: It's fine... if you have the usual conventions about the domain of a function given by a formula.  If you write $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, you don't usually have to specify that $x\neq 0$; it is assumed that you are only talking about values of $x$ for which the formula makes sense. Same here. You *could* specify $x\gt 1$ rather than $x\geq 1$ and get the same thing: a function whose domain consists precisely of all $x$ with $x\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all i think you made a mistake when writing your function definition for the range of the upper piece, i guess you wanted to write $x \leq -1$. Second of all, yes you are right it should been a more strict range because when writing a function definition in such a manner we want to put the function where it makes sense.
For example if i write

$
f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1/x  & \mbox{if } x \leq 0  \\
  x & \mbox{if } x \geq 0
 \end{array}
\right.
$

Then this function is well defined everywhere except around 0 where it doesnt make much more sense and it's a wrong way to write it.
You can do it if your function is continuous around where your 2 ranges meet.